# Studying an Ancient Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, video-games

> My prefix is simple, though often confused,
>   It's to put down an object; one other than you.
>   My infix, not truly a word, but is slang,
>   once seen when teens were late to hang with the gang.
>   My suffix, spelled stately, means 2000 pounds,
>   but alternate spellings and meanings abound.
>   Though many people and places share my whole as a name,
>   in this case the title points you to a game.

Note: You only need to find the word the riddle refers to; you'll know the game if you get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the prefix is

> lay

Could the infix be

> ayt?

and the suffix is

> ton/tonne

Not sure of the infix... but according to OP's comments below, the word is probably

> Layton

And the game, I think, is:

> Professor Games, specifically: Professor Layton and the Azran Legacy

Comment: Prefix correct.

Comment: Suffix correct.  infix is more of an overlap between them

Comment: The first suffix guess. IT's not a third separate thing

Comment: Oh I see! Updated my answer

Comment: Close enough. I meant the Professor Layton series as a whole. Take the accept. This site is the least nitpicky I've been in my life.

Comment: Also just realized I mentioned "a game" and not "games;" my bad.

Comment: By the way, the "title" line refers to his day job as an archaeology professor.

Comment: Yay! Looks like an interesting game series. I'll check it out sometime :)

Comment: Warning: Unwound Future and Azran Legacy are very sad. Also I feel that curious village, the first one, is good, but the worst of the 6. it's a good series though. I've had to look up puzzle answers because I cared more about the story.